# Is it Ok to ignore exceptions in TearDown or cleanup code

Tags: c#, exception, automation, nunit, ui-automation

I have a test suite running in Automation. All of these tests are functional UI tests. It looks like below

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    CreatePolicy();
}    

[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    EditPolicyAndValidateResults();
}

[Test]
public void Test2()
{
   EditPolicyAndValidateResults();
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{   
    DeletePolicy();
}
```

Now, the problem is `DeletePolicy()` is failing sometimes (randomly for one or two of the tests) and because of which the corresponding tests are failing. 
To circumvent the failure if have added a try catch  block to `DeletePolicy()` and it looks like the following:

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    try
    {
        DeletePolicy();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Since testing `DeletePolicy()` function is not the intent of my test cases, the approach looks fine to me. Is this correct or I am missing something here?

Comment: "Testing" DeletePolicy, and "Has a dependency on" DeletePolicy are two different things. I'd be cautious. Looking into the intermittent failure is wise. As a temporary solution until it can be looked into swallowing the exception "works".

Comment: Without knowing whether CreatePolicy causes something to persist it is hard to answer this question.  If it does, I think you have to investigate it further.  If it doesn't, perhaps you could just say this is not what I am here to test and ignore it.  I am always suspicious when people say things happen intermittently.  My experience has been that there is usually a logic flaw somewhere if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern of `Unit Testing` is: `Arrange`, `Act` then `Assert`: `AAA`.

`Setup` is just a designated method to `Arrange` the test in a better way (for example by re-setting any previously mocked/stubbed objects to save time and to avoid code duplication). It is by no means mandatory and is just a way to help test coder to code better.

`TearDown` again and in the same way is a helper and it is even farther to the generic concept of `AAA` than `Setup`. It is because in `AAA` nothing regarding destructing or cleaning up is mentioned.

So, feel free to ignore any failure in `TearDown` unless it is somehow important. Maybe there is something hidden from your eyes and you haven't taken into account yet. It may be important to make another unit test on failure point, but it totally depends on your case.